# Copy directory from a USB drive to another USB drive fails

Tags: files, usb-drive

Trying to copy a directory "max7219", including subdirectories and files, 
from one USB drive to another USB drive fails, using the command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cp -pr /dev/sdb2/media/ubuntu/rootfs/max7219 /dev/sdc2/media/ubuntu/rootfs1/
```

which shows an error:

`cp: failed to access '/dev/sdc2/media/ubuntu/rootfs1/': Not a directory`

"lsblk" (omitting the 'loopXX' devices of Snap installed apps) shows:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 931.4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1  14.4G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1  42.9M  0 part /media/ubuntu/boot
└─sdb2   8:18   1  14.4G  0 part /media/ubuntu/rootfs
sdc      8:32   1  59.7G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   1   256M  0 part /media/ubuntu/boot1
└─sdc2   8:34   1  59.4G  0 part /media/ubuntu/rootfs1
sr0     11:0    1     2G  0 rom  /cdrom
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks David

Comment: Look again at your output. It's NOT "no such device." sdc2 exists. The output is "Not a directory." Your path on sdc2 is the problem. Is 'rootfs1' a directory, or a file, or is it nonexistent?

Comment: You don't need to prepend mountpoint with path do disk partition. Think about it like this: you just access /home, not /dev/sda2/home. This is whole point of mounting: map partition (or something else that can be FS) to directory of your choice, abstracting from where are files coming from.

Answer (score 10):

### Copy at the file level

You should *copy between the mountpoints*

```
cp -pr /media/ubuntu/rootfs/max7219 /media/ubuntu/rootfs1/
```

or if you need elevated permissions to write

```
sudo cp -pr /media/ubuntu/rootfs/max7219 /media/ubuntu/rootfs1/
```

The prefixes `/dev/sdb2` `/dev/sdc2` should be removed.

### <s>Clone at the partition level</s>

If you *clone*, you should use the device names of the partitions (but then there should be no file paths)

```
sudo cp /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2
```

But this is a *very risky* operation, because a minor typing error can make you overwrite valuable data in some other partition.

Answer (score 3):

Your CLI command

`cp -pr /dev/sdb2/media/ubuntu/rootfs/max7219 /dev/sdc2/media/ubuntu/rootfs1/`

tells your system to copy, recursively, preserving the default attributes:

*mode, ownership,timestamps*, and if possible more attributes: *context, links, xattr, all*

from

/dev/sdb2/media/ubuntu/rootfs/max7219  (a directory)

to

/dev/sdc2/media/ubuntu/rootfs1/ (the name of a partition)

Copying isn't meant to use a partition as a destination, as per [man cp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cp.1.html).  Instead, you need to tell cp where to put those files inside of /dev/sdc2/